# Angular unit test in Firefox - Permission denied for ... to create wrapper for object of class XULControllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, firefox, karma-runner

Trying to fix all test to run in any browser got me to following issue:

```
Firefox 29.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.9) `test` directive should trigger event FAILED
    Permission denied for <http://localhost:8081> to create wrapper for object of class XULControllers
```

Code snippet:

```
function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="text">',
    replace: true,
    link: function postLink(scope, element) {
      scope.test = function () {
        element.triggerHandler('change');
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Test spec:

```
'use strict';

describe('`test` directive', function () {

  var element,
      $scope;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('directives'));

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = $compile(angular.element('<test></test>'))($scope);
    $scope = element.scope();
  }));

  it('should trigger event', function () {
    var spy = sinon.spy();

    element.on('change', spy)
    $scope.test();

    spy.should.have.been.called;
  });

});
```

I have no idea how could I fix this test to pass in Firefox browser. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: A similar error showed up in a costumer app after upgrading to FF 29.0.1. Permission denied for <address> to create wrapper for object of class XULControllers

Answer (score 0):

Finally we found a reason why that happens and a workaround to avoid that. I opened an issue on sinon.js repo (because it is related to sinon):

https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/issues/481

All info how to avoid is mentioned in issue